# Documentation control to prevent plagarism

Tags: ethics, writing, plagiarism, tools

I am current working on a research paper with a few other members. Are there good online documentation control tools where work contribution of different members can be tracked?

Comment: How would document control prevent plagiarism?

Comment: The question title and body don't match, please consider editing to resolve that.

Comment: Check out my answer here. Not a duplicate of the (unclear) question, but probably related. In short: it is hard to get multiple authors to use the same version control system. Probably not worth trying. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/98306/how-to-effectively-write-a-paper-of-n2-co-authors/98311#98311

Answer (score 1):

You could host the paper in a git repository and get a transactional log of who contributed what at what time. Google docs also stores a revision history, and allows concurrent collaboration.